# Can a window stay on top of a specific program?

Tags: python, pyqt

I use Window 10, python 3.5.2, PyQt-5

I can make my window stay on top of any other program using

```
setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStatsOnTophint)
```

But I can't find a way to put the window on top of only Desktop
and hide it if other program is called in front.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

If another program is switched to, you'd like to minimize it?

Comment: You can't do it with window flags. Reimplement [changeEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#changeEvent) and watch for `WindowDeactivate` events.

Comment: "...put the window on top of only Desktop..." What do you want to achieve? I don't understand this part.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! (to. jmercouris)Yes, I meant that. Minimize if switched to other program. I'll try the changeEvent. Thanks again!